# SQL If Else in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here is my query and right now I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'

on SQL Server 2005.

```
DECLARE @addHours INT, @bufferTime INT, @timeNow SMALLDATETIME,
        @lookAhead SMALLDATETIME, @todayIs SMALLDATETIME, @getWhat VARCHAR(20)

SET @addHours = 3
SET @bufferTime = 10
SET @timeNow = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108))
SET @lookAhead = DATEADD(hh, @addHours, @timeNow) --Add Look Ahead Hours
SET @lookAhead = DATEADD(mi, @bufferTime, @lookAhead) --Add buffer minutes
SET @todayIs = (SELECT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101)))
SET @getWhat = 'UpComing'

SELECT 
    RR.Emp_ID, RR.RoomName, RR.mtgName, RR.mtgTime, RR.mtgEnd, @timeNow, @lookAhead 
FROM 
    ABC.RoomReservations RR 
LEFT JOIN 
    ABC.Rooms R ON RR.RoomName = R.RoomName
WHERE 
    RR.Active = 'Y' 
    AND RR.mtgDate = @todayIs
    AND RR.Room = 'Y' 
    AND R.Viewable = 'Y'

IF @getWhat ='UpComing'
    AND RR.mtgTime >= @timeNow AND RR.mtgTime <= @lookAhead 
ELSE
    AND RR.mtgTime <= @timeNow
END

AND RR.mtgEnd >= @timeNow
ORDER BY RR.RoomName, RR.mtgTime
```

What I'm trying to do is if `@getWhat = 'UpComing'` then I want above query to have `RR.mtgTime >= @timeNow AND RR.mtgTime <= @lookAhead` condition and if `@getWhat = 'HappeningNow'` then I want `RR.mtgTime >= @timeNow AND RR.mtgTime <= @lookAhead` condition  in the `WHERE` clause.

I must be doing something wrong so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
WHERE RR.Active='Y' AND RR.mtgDate= @todayIs
  AND RR.Room='Y' AND R.Viewable = 'Y'
  AND ((@getWhat ='UpComing' AND RR.mtgTime >= @timeNow AND RR.mtgTime <= @lookAhead )
   OR (RR.mtgTime <= @timeNow))
```

Comment: Thank you @TMcKeown, just what I was looking for. For me it's like 'Can't see the forest for the trees' case.